# how to schedule a stored procedure in AZURE

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a stored procedure that I want it to run in every mid nigh
but my data base is in aZure

How can I schedule a task using sql agent?

Answer (score 8):

Azure Automation: Your SQL Agent in the Cloud: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/

make a small powershell script and schedule it in the azure dashboard.

Comment: @jaredad7 This it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-starting-a-runbook

Answer (score 4):

You can use Azure Web Job and create a console App that just call your stored procedure and schedule it to run every mid night.

Here's a sample of how to use Azure Web Job:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this site.  There is a pretty good example of what I think you ate trying to accomplish.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ms-tech_learning_with_prasant/archive/2014/07/09/scheduling-job-on-sql-azure.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Runbooks will be good. Helpful reference:

https://www.advaiya.com/creating-a-schedule-to-run-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-powershell-script-using-azure-automation/#:%7E:text=%20Creating%20a%20schedule%20to%20run%20a%20SQL,Step%203.%20PowerShell%20Script%20.%20%20More%20

Another option is ADF. Refer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/job-automation-overview?view=azuresql

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure SQL Database, it doesn't have traditional SQL Server Agent, but you can use Elastic jobs ([link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-overview?view=azuresql)).
In case you are using Azure SQL Managed Instance, it has SQL Server Agent ([link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-overview?view=azuresql)).