# How to automatically execute a stored procedure every day at a particular time in MS Azure SQL?

Tags: sql-server, azure, scheduling, sql-server-agent, azure-automation

I know how to create a `JOB` in `SQL Server` via `SQL Server Agent`. But but but, I'm very new to `MS Azure` and I have deployed my `SQL database` on `MS Azure`.

Here I want to **create a `job` which can run a `stored procedure` automatically** on a specific time of the day, via `SQL Server Agent`. I searched a lot and came to know that ["SQL Server Agent is not an available feature in MS Azure"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/). I find a [help link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630851/how-to-schedule-a-stored-procedure-in-azure) but it was really difficult to get a viable solution.

Can someone share a simple solution so I can get rid on this issue!!

Comment: You can use this feature: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/ - SQL Job Agent on MS Azure has been disabled by MS - Also see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309474/best-way-to-schedule-sql-job-in-microsoft-azure

Comment: Yes, I solved it with *Scheduler* :-)

Answer (score 1):

Azure doesn't provide SQL Server Agent job feature. But it has a very dynamic and vast feature i.e. **Scheduler**. Scheduler schedules almost everything whatever you want to trigger on Azure. Whether it is DB object, App Services etc.

So, you can use **Scheduler** on azure to do your work done. For more details go to this link.

[Scheduler Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/)

Comment: I had tried it to get my solution. By the way, thank you so much. :-)

Comment: Plus 1 for you. @Prateek Sharma